# Creating a Promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, frontend, backend

I want this function `tagFindOrCreate` to only execute if the first function is finished:

```
func.tweetCreate(bmTweet, user)
    .then(function () {
            func.tagFindOrCreate(bmTweet, bmtTag, user)
    })
```

Help me create a promise for this function:

```
tweetCreate: function (tweet, user) {
    Tweet.create(tweet, function (err, tweet) {
        user[0].tweets.push(tweet)
        user[0].save()
        console.log("Tweet saved.")
        return Promise.resolve()
    })
}
```

Comment: What is `Tweet`? Is this from a third party library?

Comment: No, it's a mongoose model that I created.

Comment: So if you wrote Tweet.create why not just have it return a Promise instead of support callbacks, rather than wrap it in one?

Comment: @Jamiec If I did that, the function would become very large. Also, I wanted to reuse the Tweet.create without creating the tag every time.

Comment: @AnshAgarwal that makes zero sense. Either support callbacks or Pomises, theres no need for both

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, I understand. I just wanted to implement and see how both of them work. I know that one is a replacement for the other. But, I just wanted to try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the promise constructor to create a promise and `tweetCreate()` should return that promise.

Call to `Tweet.create(...)` should be *inside* the executor function *(function that is passed to the promise constructor)* and from inside of the callback function of `Tweet.create(...)`, you need to call the `resolve()` function to fulfil the promise.

You need to change the implementation of your function to as shown below:

```
tweetCreate: function (tweet, user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Tweet.create(tweet, function (err, tweet) {
          user[0].tweets.push(tweet);
          user[0].save();
          resolve();      //  <--- this will resolve the promise
        });
    });
}
```

Calling `resolve()` will fulfil the promise leading to the invocation of the callback function of the `then()` method.

---

#### Edit

You mentioned in a comment that `Tweet` is a mongoose model; In that case, you don't need a explicitly create a promise. Mongoose provides a promise-based API for creating and saving documents in the database and that is what you should use instead of creating promises yourself.

Comment: You should not need to use the Promise constructor nowadays in most cases. `util.promisify` is available for this purpose, and most libraries have built-in promises including mongoose models.

Comment: @ExplosionPills OP didn't mention mongoose in the question but your point has been duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

This would be as follows:

```
tweetCreate: function (tweet, user) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Tweet.create(tweet, function (err, tweet) {
            user[0].tweets.push(tweet);
            user[0].save();
            console.log("Tweet saved.")
            resolve();
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Tweet` is a mongoose model, its `create` method will already return a promise as long as you don't pass a callback. This means you can move your callback logic to where promise resolution occurs. The simplest way to do this would be to use [an `async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
tweetCreate: async function (tweetContents, user) {
  const createdTweet = await Tweet.create(tweetContents);
  user[0].tweets.push(createdTweet);
  user[0].save();
  console.log('tweet saved');
}
```

**A note on error handling:** An `async` function will already return a promise or potentially throw an error (if there is an error in `Tweet.create`). The above code will propagate the error, so make sure that if you are using `async`/`await` you wrap your calling code in `try`/`catch` or make use of `.catch` to handle the errors where it's needed. It's up to the logic of your app to decide whether you need to catch the error in `tweetCreate` itself, or whether you can propagate it into the application code level where it can be caught and handled, but just be aware of the need to handle potential promise errors.

---

For the sake of completeness, you *can* promisify `Tweet.create`. It's common for library methods to return promises nowadays, so manual promisification is rarely necessary. Keep this in mind if you feel the need to promisify ... the library may already have a mechanism for it.

You can do this manually simply by using a `Promise` constructor. This takes a callback which takes a `resolve` argument which you can call from within another callback to resolve the promise:

```
return Promise(resolve => {
   Tweet.create(tweet, (error, createdTweet) {
     ...
     resolve();
   });
});
```

Node.js has a built-in [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function as well, so using a Promise constructor is probably unnecessary for this purpose. You could do:

```
const createTweet = util.promisify(Tweet.create);
const createdTweet = await createTweet(tweet);
...
```

**NOTE:** the above is just an example. It's not necessary to do this with mongoose models.